# Installing VIM with Python support locally without sudo

Tags: vim, python

I'm trying to install VIM with Python support on Linux without sudo, but for some reason VIM always gets installed without python ( -python in vim --version )

1. I first installed Python locally by downloading the `tgz` file and decompressing it in `$HOME`
2. Then I `cd` to that directory and ran:
   `./configure --prefix=$HOME/python && make && make install`

I already got VIM installed without Python support, so I just went to the VIM source directory and ran the following:

3. `./configure --prefix=$HOME --with-features=huge --enable-pythoninterp  --without-x  --with-python-config-dir=/home/<user>/python/lib/python2.7/config`
4. `make && make install`

VIM so far still shows `-python` and `echo has('python')` returns `0`

The `<vim-src>/src/auto/config.log` file shows that it's trying to use the system python:

```
configure:5486: checking for python
configure:5504: found /usr/bin/python 
.
.
configure:5740: result: no: PYTHON DISABLED
```

but fails and end up not adding python support!.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Hi there, this may not directly related to your problem but I suggest you have a look at linuxbrew. It will allow you to install many software to your own home directory, vim, Emacs, pyenv, rbenv etc etc.

Comment: ruby is not installed on the machine I'm using, and I can't install it since I don't have sudo :(

Comment: You can install linuxbrew by git `git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew.git ~/.linuxbrew` but it does need some development libraries and tools to build other software. Anyway, I still suggest you give it a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `./configure` was trying to use the system python executable in `/usr/bin/python` and since I wasn't running it with sudo, it was failing for some reason.

`./configure` looks in your `$PATH` for the python executable, so I had to add the local python **bin** dir to my `$Path` before the `/usr/bin` dir.

So adding something like this `export PATH=$HOME/python/bin:$PATH` in `.bashrc` made it work.

Note that the local python **bin** directory has to be **before** the `/usr/bin/` dir in `$PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of vim `./configure` and the files it generated (`./src/auto/config.h`, `./src/auto/config.status`) for the Python support.

Also make sure you're executing the right `vim` binary.

Comment: Thanks spuk, the `./configure` output actually shows it was using the system python executable not the local version of python, I didn't notice this before. I've updated the question with extra details about the log output.